# MATLAB parallel loop with slight delays

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

I have a parallel loop in matlab shown below. Is there a way to make sure the loops are not running simultaneously but with  a slight delay? I am open to use batch or spmd also but have limited knowledge of them and will appreciate any help.
I am calling another program, myprogexe.exe, but this program needs to access a specific port on  a pc and multiple requests cant go in. hence i need to make sure there is a very slight delay in requests. myprogexe.exe is a very cumputationally heavy code itself (takes about 10 mins for each input to run)

```
parfor i=1:length(MinorRoots)
runmodels = MinorRoots{i};
cmd = ['$myprogexe -v 2014.2  ', runmodels];

[status, result] = system(cmd);
end
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a `parfor` loop if you can't run multiple instances of `myprogexe` without issue?

Comment: The issue is in initiation of the myprogexe runs, it can not be initiated at the same time, but with  a fraction of a second difference in initiation of the run, they can. Each full run of myprogexe takes 10 minutes or more, so if I can initiate runs in 1 second delays, by the end of 11th minute i will have the whole process excuted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `spmd` to do this, but note that the following approach isn't completely ideal because it adds additional synchronisation points.

```
spmd
    origLimit = length(MinorRoots);
    loopLimit = numlabs * ceil(origLimit/numlabs);
    for i = labindex:numlabs:loopLimit
        labBarrier; % synchronise all workers

        if i <= origLimit
            pause(labindex-1); % timing offset
            ... run your code ...
        end
    end
end
```